No se visualiza imagenes al publicar proyecto NET core
Tengo un proyecto en net core, el cual al ser publicado no muestra las imágenes ya que las rutas cambian y toman el nombre de la aplicación,
Proyecto en debug:
http://localhost/images/"nombre imagen"

Proyecto publicado:
http://localhost/"Nombre aplicación"/"nombre imagen"

La propiedad de la imagen copy always se encuentra activa.
Para que la imagen sea visible en desarrollo tengo que asignar la ruta:
imgParkingElement.src = 'images/Parking.png';

Y para que la imagen sea visible en el proyecto publicado tengo que cambiar la ruta a
imgParkingElement.src = '/AMRFleetManager/images/Parking.png';

AMRFleetManager es el nombre de la aplicación dado en la publicación en iis.
Ya he intentado con lo siguiente:
"~/Images/prueba.png"

Lo cual no funciono.
Se intenta acceder a las imágenes desde los archivos JS
De ante mano muchas gracias por su tiempo.


Interesante, primero te recomiendo que hagas el [tour]

otra cosa si mas no me equivoco puedes hacer algo asi:
var basePath = '/AMRFleetManager/'; y luego: imgParkingElement.src = basePath + 'images/Parking.png'; con la finalidad de obtener el path para las imagenes aunque tambien puede ser algo como: imgParkingElement.src = '@Url.Content("~/images/Parking.png")'; que deberia resolver la url de la imagen ... prueba y me dices si te sirve algunas de estas opciones ...

No me ha funcionado ninguna de las dos opciones
Si realizo este cambio var basePath = '/AMRFleetManager/'; la imagen ya no se muestra cuando ejecuto el proyecto  pero si en el publicado.

Si realizo este cambio la ruta que toma la imagen es la siguiente:
http://localhost/AMRFleetManager/Layout/FloorPlan/@Url.Content(%22~/images/Aruco_logo.png%22), la cual es incorrecta

bueno entonces lo mas probable es que IIS tenga configuracion diferente del Document_ROOT ... Verifica eso

Disculpa la pregunta, pero esta parte exactamente donde se tiene que revisar ?

Sabes que es IIS???

Si y e usado IIS, pero no se en que parte de la configuración del sitio se ve esta parte Document_ROOT

creo que aqui dice donde esta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764451/22473069

o es eso o hay algun routing o algo parecido para las imagenes que debes configurar; puedes preguntarle al administrador del proyecto si tiene alguna configuracion especifica para entornos locales de desarollo en IIS... ya que las imagenes no se ven correctamente en el local...
